# Get value for href into more classes

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm using c# 
and i have project simple C# to use anlayes page by C sharp with WebBrowser 
My Program geting Value href(string) from page ..

### I'm Load url to page in WebBrowser and i want get Value href from it

I know one methed do it us (id) GetEltmentByid proprties 
but no't work Becoz href value into more classes on id

Look Example url :
https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10155655424600112&id=305901075111&_rdr

---

do scan Eltment on firfox 
and find this :

href="/video_redirect/?src=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-video-m-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhvideo-ak-xta1%2Fv%2Ft42.1790-2%2F11246819_10155655425285112_551536335_n.mp4%3Fefg%3DeyJybHIiOjMwOSwicmxhIjo1MTIsInFlX2dyb3VwcyI6WyJlXzA0MDNfMSJdfQ%253D%253D%26oh%3D8b2e73521a3a6625aca40b9dd05855c8%26oe%3D5565DDBA%26__gda__%3D1432739635_93ea3282e7999210402e8128cbd5605c&source=misc&id=10155655424600112&refid=52&**tn**=F"

i Want this Value :
in MessageBox

Thanks ..

Comment: please remember to focus on spelling and grammar when writing a question

Comment: @Jonesy I agree with spelling, but we can't expect everyone to be grammatically correct. Remember english isn't a first language for all.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel What we can expect is a *clear* and *concise* example of a current or previous attempt. I.e. [ask]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Why can't you use `document.getElementById("id").href`?